# How can we retrieve the same information as getfacl and setfacl functions using java on ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, posix, acl

We are trying to manipulate the acl on ubuntu using java.We tried using AclFileAttributeView from java 7 nio.file.attributes package .But it has the implementation supported only for nfsv4 filesystem.

Using [PosixFileAttributeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html) we are getting only posix permissions which does not contain any extra acl entries other than basic posix permissions.

Is there any other way out to get the  [posix ACL](http://www.cs.unc.edu/cms/help/help-articles/posix-acls-in-linux)  information in Ubuntu using java?

Answer (score 0):

Check out JCIFS library to set the Windows ACL permissions via SMB from your java code running on Ubuntu.